# Django Admin - Add button to create duplicate fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to add (+) button on the admin page to duplicate a field. So say I have a field for Father/Mother, and in case someone has a step father or a step mother I could hit the plus button on Father/Mother and duplicate the field and update step Father/Mother info.

I want to be able to do this with other fields as well and not just these two.

I am a newbie. So can you please help me with detailed instructions for how to do this please?

I have been trying to source this info for some time now...but :(

Thanks,
Codie

I have a very simple model structure and no forms as of now. In the future I may have some forms.

```
class _musi(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    born = models.DateField()
    died = models.DateField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    reason_of_death = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthplace = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    father = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mother = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
 Django Inlines
```

also to work with inline may be you need to make some changes with your models as you did not show your models so i am not sure about this.

You can refer to [Inlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045064/django-admin-inline)
[Django Admin Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.extra)

**Edit :**

Please add all fields as Foreignkey with your current model _musi .
You should read how to use [Foreign Key relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)
For now if you want with fields father and mother then do like below.

```
class Father(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Mother(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class _musi(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    born = models.DateField()
    died = models.DateField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    reason_of_death = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthplace = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    father = models.ForeignKey(Father)
    mother = models.ForeignKey(Mother)
```

Please implement same with your other fields which  need this functionality.

Comment: I have a very simple model structure and no forms as of now. In the future I may have some forms.


class _musi(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    born = models.DateField()
    died = models.DateField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    reason_of_death = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthplace = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    father = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mother = models.CharField(max_length=200)