# Multiple Models in one Admin Screen

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have models:

```
class Acessories(models.Model):
    clother = models.ForeignKey(Clother, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    acessories_type = models.ForeignKey(AcessoriesType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

class Clother(models.Model):
    MALE = 'MA'
    FEMALE = 'FE'
    UNISEX = 'UN'
    GENDER_CHOICES = ((MALE, 'Male'), (FEMALE, 'Female'), (UNISEX, 'Unisex'))

    commodity = models.ForeignKey(Commodity, related_name='commodity', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Commodity, related_name='color')
    material = models.ManyToManyField(Commodity, related_name='material')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=UNISEX)
```

How can I make it in one Admin screen?
Need to see and edit this as it was one model.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this or visit this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) for more information

```
class AccessoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Acessories

@admin.register(Clothes)
class ClothesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AccessoryInline,
    ]
```

Comment: InLine give me several lines to one main model. But i need to combine 3 models at one screen without multiplying any of model. As if it were one model.

Comment: You mean 4 models `Acessories`, `Clother`, `AcessoriesType` and `Clother`

Comment: no, I mean Commodity (common atributes for different goods), Clother (common atributes for different clothers), Acessories. And I want to open Acessories and fill all fields - first commoditry, then clother, then acessories. Not multiply.

Comment: @D.Make It seems like your answer. What do you mean by multiply? I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but a model here refers to a database table and two database tables cannot be combined unless they have same number of columns. For combining two or more models as a one model, see `QuerySet.union()` method.

Comment: In your case, you can't combine these two models as a one model. One way is to use javascript in your admin interface and stop creating more instances of the model. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045064/how-to-show-only-one-image-in-django-admin-inline) answer